# PHP Database Entry Issue (Wampserver)

Tags: php, wampserver

I'm a complete code nooby and months ago built a basic website before my server mobo died. I just rebuilt the server and copied over all my website/db code I had backed up to my desktop. To the best of my knowledge everything is the same between php code and database setup.

My site works 90% except for when I go to input data. I get an error of "waiting for entry" opposed to the expected "New record created successfully". The relative if statement is **on the very bottom** of the below code.

Does anyone by chance have any clue why after inputting all my proper data that it does not trigger the "New record created successfully"? If it means anything the code works fine on my desktop and unless I did something really dumb I copy/pasta'd everything appropriately to this server :(

```
<?php

 //Connect to database

include('database.php');

   //grab user logged in for database insertion

   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

   $ses_sql = mysqli_query($dbcon,"select username from t_login where username = '$user_check' ");

   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

   $login_session = $row['username'];

 // Create DB Variable

 $login_session = $row['username'];
 $excercisename = (isset($_POST['excercisename']) ? $_POST['excercisename'] : null);
 $setcount = (isset($_POST['setcount']) ? $_POST['setcount'] : null);
 $rep1 = (isset($_POST['rep1']) ? $_POST['rep1'] : null);
 $rep2 = (isset($_POST['rep2']) ? $_POST['rep2'] : null);
 $rep3 = (isset($_POST['rep3']) ? $_POST['rep3'] : null);
 $rep4 = (isset($_POST['rep4']) ? $_POST['rep4'] : null);
 $rep5 = (isset($_POST['rep5']) ? $_POST['rep5'] : null);
 $rep6 = (isset($_POST['rep6']) ? $_POST['rep6'] : null);
 $rep7 = (isset($_POST['rep7']) ? $_POST['rep7'] : null);
 $rep8 = (isset($_POST['rep8']) ? $_POST['rep8'] : null);
 $weight1 = (isset($_POST['number1']) ? $_POST['number1'] : null);
 $weight2 = (isset($_POST['number2']) ? $_POST['number2'] : null);
 $weight3 = (isset($_POST['number3']) ? $_POST['number3'] : null);
 $weight4 = (isset($_POST['number4']) ? $_POST['number4'] : null);
 $weight5 = (isset($_POST['number5']) ? $_POST['number5'] : null);
 $weight6 = (isset($_POST['number6']) ? $_POST['number6'] : null);
 $weight7 = (isset($_POST['number7']) ? $_POST['number7'] : null);
 $weight8 = (isset($_POST['number8']) ? $_POST['number8'] : null);
 $cardio = (isset($_POST['cardio']) ? $_POST['cardio'] : null);
 $duration = (isset($_POST['duration']) ? $_POST['duration'] : null);
 $weight = (isset($_POST['weight']) ? $_POST['weight'] : null);
 $comments = (isset($_POST['comments']) ? $_POST['comments'] : null);


 //Execute the insert statement
 if(!empty($excercisename)){
 $sql = "INSERT INTO t_workout (username, excercisename, setcount, set1reps, set2reps, set3reps, set4reps, set5reps, set6reps, set7reps, set8reps, set1weight, set2weight, set3weight, set4weight, set5weight, set6weight, set7weight, set8weight, cardio, cardio_dur, weight, comments) 
 VALUES ('$login_session', '$excercisename', '$setcount', '$rep1', '$rep2', '$rep3', '$rep4', '$rep5', '$rep6', '$rep7', '$rep8', '$weight1', '$weight2', '$weight3', '$weight4', '$weight5', '$weight6', '$weight7', '$weight8', '$cardio', '$duration', '$weight', '$comments')";
 }

  if($weight > 0){
     $sql = "INSERT INTO t_workout (username, weight)
     VALUES ('$login_session', '$weight')";
  }

if(isset($sql)){
    if ($dbcon->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Waiting for entry.";
}
}
$dbcon->close();
?>
```

Comment: If your weight is set then the $sql overwrites the first insert.  You probably want to run both inserts and not just the last one.

Comment: yea I remember that part. I forgot exactly why but on the site I specified that if you want to record your personal weight, leave everything else blank. But even then on my site entering only weight returns a "Waiting for entry" Only thing I can think of is that Wampserver on my desktop is 3.0.6, and on my server it is 3.1.0. Could that be the problem by chance? But I hesitate to think that because it's just code correct? and all the tables/php is there :(

Comment: I'm pretty lost. I uninstalled everything, installed the same Wampserver 3.0.6 on server. Placed in all my code from desktop for website/database over so that it should be identical. But still get the "Waiting for entry" error whereas that problem does not exist on desktop. Am very sad lol.

Comment: Can you add `<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the code to ensure errors are reported.

Answer (score 0):

Sweet mercy I am sorry for anyone that looked into this lol.

I solved it. The code and everything is fine (well, for how amateur the code is).

The issue is with wampserver, in my mysql.ini file there was a semi-colon commenting out sql-mode. I simply removed the semicolon and now it works. I don't know what sql mode in the ini-file did...but its something I had edited in the ini file months ago that I caught when comparing all my wampserver config files.

**;sql-mode=""**